# Dynamic rows & columns for Gridview

Tags: c#, sql, gridview

I have a scenario where I have 3 tables (`Employees`, `Tasks`, `EmployeeTaskTimes`) I need to generated a gridview in c# with list of `Task` on the vertical scale (rows), and `Employees` on horizontal scale (columns) and fill in the values from the `EmployeeTaskTimes`.

basic layout for the tables is:

> *Employees:*
>       IdEmp;
>       Name;
>
> *Tasks:*
>   IdTask
>   Title;
>
> *EmployeeTaskTimes:*
>   IdEmpTaskTime;
>   IdTask
>   IdEmp;
>   TimeTaken;

I have run into three headaches that I need suggestions:

1. Creating columns based on the dataset from `Employees`. (dynamically?)
2. A reasonable query(s) to generate a dataset consumable by the gridview
3. bind the values to the grid.

Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: You can use the SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDataAdapter classes to pull your tables into memory from the database, and, using the BindingSource class, bind the data between your GridView's DataSource and the database tables. If you set the GridView's DataSource to the BindingSource, the columns should automatically generate from your tables, if thats what you want.

Comment: I do not understand why you need to create the column dynamically ? You already know the content of your tables. Another thing, it seems to me that you did not really did any research. You can't expect us to give you the code you need just like that. You must 1) Give us some code sample, 2) SHow us you already made some research and did not post your answer straight to StackOverFlow and finally show us what you tryed and what is not working.

Comment: So, I've done many a gridview attempts. ie:<br>

Comment: '<asp:GridView ID="gvTasks"/> 'with code to say: 'gvTasks.DataSource = Datatable.get().... 'gvTasks.Databind();

Comment: I'm not particularly fond of Guigui's comment about 'show us you already made some research'.  I've been trying to find a simple way without coding thousands of lines of code.  The 3 tables vary in their content (ie you'd have 5 employees one time, 7 the next).  fixing the columns doesn't help.  How can that be represented in a gridview?  normally I'd be defining the columns in the aspx. But that doesn't work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use Pivot

[msdn article on PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks!  the pivot table example was what I needed to see.  Still a bit confusing, but it got the job done.. thansk!